# Connect to GreenPlum Database from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, oledb, greenplum

I am trying to connect to greenplum database from a .net application. Greenplum supports odbc and oledb, but i am not sure how the connectionstring and all should be. can anybody help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look: http://deebujacob.blogspot.com/2011/06/cnet-and-greenplum.html

Comment: They used Postgre SQL to get started.  So try that first: http://connectionstrings.com/postgre-sql

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver (psqlODBC):

```
Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP address;Port=5432;Database=mydb;Uid=uname;Pwd=passwd;
```

Refer to  http://connectionstrings.com/postgre-sql.

The free driver can be downloaded from http://pgfoundry.org/projects/psqlodbc/.

If you want a commercially supported Greenplum driver try http://www.datadirect.com/products/odbc/greenplum/index.html.